# Finite number of zeros if $f$ is analytic and satisfies homologous condition

Tags: complex-analysis

I was reading Conway's complex analysis and I encounter the following exercise. I appreciate if someone can help me.

> Let $G$ be open and suppose that $\gamma$ is closed rectifiable curve in $G$ such that $\gamma \approx 0$ (i.e., $\gamma$ is homologous to zero). Set $r= d(\{ \gamma \}, \operatorname{fr}(G))$ ( $\{\gamma\}$ is the trace of the curve) and $H=\{z\in {\bf{C}}: \operatorname {Ind}_\gamma (z)=0\}$.
>
> (a) Show that $\{z: d(z,\operatorname{fr}(G) )<r/2\}\subset H$
>
> (b) Use part (a) to show that if $f:G\to \bf{C}$ is analytic then $f(z)=\alpha$ has at most a finite number of solutions $z$ such that $\operatorname {Ind}_\gamma (z)\not=0$.

Let $W$ be the complement of $\{\gamma \}$ in $\bf{C}$. Then $\operatorname {Ind}_\gamma$ is constant in each component $V$ of $W$. If $V$ is unbounded $\operatorname {Ind}_\gamma (V)=\{0\}$ or if $V\cap ({\bf{C}}-G)\not=\varnothing$, the homologous condition implies that $\operatorname {Ind}_\gamma (z)=0$. Therefore we have to show that any $z$ satisfying $d(z,\operatorname{fr}(G) )<r/2$ is either in the unbounded component or there is a $w$ in the complement of $G$ such that $w$ and $z$ are in the same component.

Suppose to the contrary that $d(z,\operatorname{fr}(G) )<r/2$ and neither $z$ is in the unbounded component nor there is a $w\in {\bf{C}}-G$ such that $z$ and $w$ are in the same component. If $V$ is the component containing $z$, then $V\subset G$ and $V$ is bounded($\ldots$)

(b) We will show that $\operatorname{Cl}(A)\subset G$. Suppose there is a $z\in \operatorname{Cl}(A)$ such that $z\in \operatorname{fr}(G)$. Then $\exists w\in B(z,r/2)\cap A$,and so $d(w,\operatorname{fr}(G))\le d(w,z)<r/2$ and so $\operatorname{Ind}_\gamma(w)=0$, contradicting $w\in A$. Also $A$ is bounded because does not contains the unbounded component and so $\operatorname{Cl}(A)$. Hence is a compact set.

Let $K=f^{-1}(\alpha)\cap \operatorname{Cl}(A)$. Then $K$ is closed and $K\subset \operatorname{Cl}(A)$ therefore compact as well. If $f$ is not constante then $K$ is finite, if not, there is a infinite set  $\{z_1,z_2,\ldots \}\subset K$ and then the set admits a limit point and $f$ would be constant. Then $K$ is finite. If $z$ is in $G$, $\operatorname{Ind}_\gamma(z)\not=0$ and $f(z)=\alpha$ then $z\in f^{-1}(\alpha)\cap A\subset K$ and so only we have a finite number of those values.

Comment: The homologous condition? What condition is that?

Comment: $\operatorname{Ind(\gamma, a)}=0$ for all $a \in \mathbb C\setminus G$, where $G$ is an open set of $\mathbb C$ where a function is analytic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to prove it directly.

Let $z$ such that $d(z,\operatorname{fr}(G)) < r/2$. Then there is a $w\in \operatorname{fr}(G) \cap B_{r/2}(z)$. Since $w\in \operatorname{fr}(G)$, by definition of $r$ we have $B_r(w) \cap \{\gamma\} = \varnothing$. Then $B_r(w)$ is a connected set containing $z$ and intersecting $\mathbb{C}\setminus G$, hence $V \cap (\mathbb{C}\setminus G) \neq \varnothing$, whence $\operatorname{Ind}_\gamma (z) = 0$.

It follows that $A = \{z\in G : \operatorname{Ind}_\gamma(z) \neq 0\}$ is relatively compact in $G$.

Comment: Thanks I think I got the $(b)$ part. We will show that $\operatorname{Cl}(A)\subset G$. Suppose there is a $z\in \operatorname{Cl}(A)$ such that $z\in \operatorname{fr}(G)$. Then $\exists w\in B(z,r/2)\cap A$,and so $d(w,\operatorname{fr}(G))\le d(w,z)<r/2$ and so $\operatorname{Ind}_\gamma(w)=0$, contradicting $w\in A$. Also $A$ is bounded because does not contains the unbounded component and so $\operatorname{Cl}(A)$. Hence is a compact set.

Comment: Let $K=f^{-1}(\alpha)\cap \operatorname{Cl}(A)$. Then $K$ is closed and $K\subset \operatorname{Cl}(A)$ therefore compact. If $f$ is not constant then $K$ is finite,  suppose not, then there is an infinite set  $\{z_1,z_2,\ldots \}\subset K$ and the set admits a limit point and $f$ would be constant. Then $K$ is finite. If $z$ is in $G$, $\operatorname{Ind}_\gamma(z)\not=0$ and $f(z)=\alpha$ then $z\in f^{-1}(\alpha)\cap A\subset K$ and so only we have a finite number of those values.